# Is it correct to refer to a single " (double quotation mark) in plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I was sure that the `"` character is called *double quotation mark* and `'` is called *single quotation mark* -- until I opened my InDesign CS6 and noticed that `"` is called *double quotation marks* (sic). Plural.

- Is it at least grammatical and syntactically correct?
- Is it common?

I never saw that `"` is referred as plural, but on the other hand Adobe is creditable company and InDesign is creditable software.

ps InDesign CS6 is from 2012 year, and since I have not tried newer versions,the wording might be corrected since then.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a sentence, or anything like one, so it's hard (or impossible) to say whether it's grammatical, but it clearly doesn't fit the pattern of the other items in that menu.

Comment: Have you looked up "quotation mark" in a dictionary? Most should define that term. If dictionary definitions are confusing or unclear and you think that someone here can clarify, then feel free to ask about that.

Comment: @MarcInManhattan, I know what quoation marks are. :-) I simply cannot understand why Adobe decided to refer to each of the double quotation marks as "quotation marks" (plural) instead of "quotation mark" (singular). I want to understand whether this practise is widespread.

Comment: Adobe is going against the [mainstream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#:~:text=The%20double%20quotation%20mark%20is,prime%20serve%20quite%20different%20purposes.). This is a character (singular) called a 'double quotation mark': `"` (they also come in left and right varieties) and this `"word"` is surrounded by double quotation marks.

Comment: @jsv Yes, that's why I suggested looking in dictionaries; if you check a few, you will either get consistent answers (suggesting that that usage is fairly standard) or differing answers (suggesting that varying usages are possible). I think that that will be more authoritative than anything that someone here might say.

Comment: my question on Adobe forums: https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/why-indesign-calls-double-quotation-mark-quot-double-quotation-marks-quot-plural/m-p/12641533

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is variation in use, as you have found.  I find both quotation mark and quotation marks equally acceptable, when referring to a single character (which may be formed of two inverted or raised commas)

However, as quotation marks tend to be used in pairs, when referring to a pair, you must use "marks":

> You should enclose a direct quote in quotation marks.